# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added

Tags: webforms

Why do I get this error message: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page?

I haven't been using HTML comment to hide an ASP.NET server tag and there is no other ScriptManager in the entire project.

Markup:

```
 <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
</div>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>     
            <asp:Label ID="lblCount" CssClass="LikeCount" Text='<%#Eval("LikeCount") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>                                      
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbAddOne" CssClass="LikeAddOne" Text="+1" runat="server" OnClick="lbAddOne_Click" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ReviewID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code-behind:

```
    protected void lbAddOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton _sender = (LinkButton)sender;
    string ReviewID = _sender.CommandArgument;
    int UserID = ((User)Session["LoggedInUser"]).UserID;

    lblCount.Text = (int.Parse(lblCount.Text) + 1).ToString();

    CategoryAccess.AddLikeReview(ReviewID, UserID);
}
```

Comment: Are you using a master page with its own ScriptManager and also declaring a ScriptManager on the page?

Comment: I think you can put just a Single Script manager at a page ,but using Multiply Update Panel's will do the trick i guess.

Comment: Are you completely sure you don't have another one anywhere else, for example in a Master Page?

Comment: Could you maybe provide us with whole markup code? Do you use `MasterPage`? If you do, is the code you provided from `MasterPage` or regular page that uses `MasterPage`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a master page, but the page I have the problem in is not the master page and im not using any other ScriptManager in my project

Comment: Are you using any other kind of manager such as ToolkitScriptManager?

Comment: Nothing more then this: dbConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString; And it's not on the same page.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party server controls?

Comment: It's because the ScriptManager is in a datalist! That was stupid! :) Thanks for helping

Comment: A prime example of where posting your whole code would help, rather than the bit that you think is the problem!  Good work for fixing it - you can answer your own question and accept it as the answer (this is encouraged).

Comment: try, I should have posted that aswell, but 700 lines is alitelbit to much imo.

Answer (score 0):

just add a reference to scriptmanager in the masterpage, then it will be available to any page referencing the master. this will be easier to maintain in the long run rather than adding references to individual pages.